# Download XLSX getting corrupted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to convert a HTML table to XLSX uisng AngularJS or even plain JavaScript.

When I'm converting to XLS using below its downloading fine and a XLS file is opening.

```
var blob = new Blob([template], {type: "data:application/vnd.ms-excel"});
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "myExcel.xls");
```

But, my requirement wants the file in XLSX, so I changed the MIME type and extension of file in the same code like below,

```
var blob = new Blob([template], {type: "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "myExcel.xlsx");
```

But when I'm opening the downloaded xlsx file its corrupted and MS office is trowing error popup.

What I'm doing wrong and how I can convert a HTML table to **XLSX**?
Even alternate ideas also accepted.

**PS:** The table is quite complicated, rows within columns and all, so plugins like ALASQL, JS-XLSX is not helping.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Agramer Its seems like its not possible to it from Angular side. So we have done this in Service side (JAVA) and download the XLSX sent in response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I am experiencing similar issue with Vue.js.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may lie in the type XLSX. This post states that it is a zipped set of XLS files. Have a read through. I cannot comment, because my score isn't over 50 yet, so I'm posting as an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516332/1425168

Answer (score 1):

just try to change mime-type

change it to `application/vnd.ms-excel` it works fine with XLSX also.

```
var blob = new Blob([template], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "myExcel.xlsx");
```

Try this code.

Comment: Already tried, its not working, corrupted file. Seems like MS have update some XLSX prorperties.

Comment: it will ask for yes no, if you press yes it should open up. can you try and let me know?

Comment: No it won't ask for Yes or No. It will say file extension is invalid and blah blah. Just press OK and exit.

Comment: can you create fiddle or pen?

Answer (score 0):

try to edit the file type,

```
const blob = new Blob([data], {
    // type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;'    //old 
       type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;
charset=utf-8'    //try this new
          })
```