# Exporting JSON to Excel is saving in .xls format! Require to save in '.xlsx' format

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

Exporting data from UI to Excel. But it is saving in '.xls' format. Need to save in '.xlsx' format.

> Here is the link of my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavk_19/8r3t6ovo/)

I tried to change the uri to

```
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,'
```

But Showing the downloaded file in '.xlsx' format corrupted.

One field contains the data like

```
'<p><strong>Test</strong></p>'
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ??

Here my field data is with html tags & style e.g Bold/Italic/Hyperlink etc.
Expected output is conversion that text with styling like if any text is bold , Ine xcel also it should be exported like Bold text. Same with other styles.

Comment: See this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498713/how-to-export-an-html-table-as-an-xlsx-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export an html table as an xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498713/how-to-export-an-html-table-as-an-xlsx-file)

Comment: From backend, one of my field contains html tags. Expected output : In excel , it should convert that tag to text with respective styling in excel. No where I found this question or answer

Answer (score 2):

As `.xls` and `.xlsx` are completely different formats you can't simply change the extension to get that working.

I'll suggest you to send the data to the backend via a form, and let the backend generate de `.xlsx` file, there are a lot of libraries in a lot of languages that can help you with that:

- Python: [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- Node: [`nodex-xlsx`](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx)
- PHP: [`PHP_XLSXWriter`](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter)
- Java: [`Apache POI`](https://poi.apache.org/)
- .NET: [`EPPlus`](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)

If you can't use a backend solution, you can use [`js-xlsx`](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library which can generate `.xlsx` files in the client-side, you can see [the demo](http://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html) of exporting a table, or construct the file like this:

```
var filename = "write.xlsx";
var data = [
    ['Code-Page ID', 'Name', 'ACP   OEMCP', 'Windows NT 3.1', 'Windows NT 3.1', 'Windows 95'],
  [1200, 'Unicode (BMP of ISO/IEC-10646)', null, 'X', 'X', '*'],
  [1250, 'Windows 3.1 Eastern European', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
 ];

var ws_name = "Code Page Support";
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, ws_name);
XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename);
```

Comment: Developing application with SAP UI5 & ABAP. Front end, I can use Javascript or JQuerry

Comment: Updated de answer with a pure client-side solution @PranavKumar :)

Comment: I tried  this one. But here issue with the data. My data is in HTML format like bold/italic.

e.g 

var data = [
    ['Code-Page ID', 'Name', 'ACP   OEMCP', 'Windows NT 3.1', 'Windows NT 3.1', 'Windows 95'],
  [1200, 'Unicode (BMP of ISO/IEC-10646)', null, 'X', '<p><strong>Test</p>', '*'],
  [1250, 'Windows 3.1 Eastern European', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
 ];

Comment: Sorry for asking you again. Can u help me how to pares the data manually ?   I tried with jQuery.parseHTML() . In excel also data should be reflected as bold/Italic & hyperlink