# Saving as Excel using Window.saveAs function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code

```
 var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Pricing Sheet</x:Name>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
 var tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='2px' style='float:left;'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var tab_text = tab_text + "<tr>"; 
    var tab_text = tab_text + "<td>";
    var tab_text = tab_text + "<b>Some data</b>";
    var tab_text = tab_text + "</td>";   
    var tab_text = tab_text + "</tr>";
    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
 tab_text = tab_text + '</body></html>';
```

This is basically just creating a table with some data in it

I am saving this table as shown below

```
var fileName = 'Pricing' + '.xls';
    var blob = new Blob([tab_text], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8" })
    window.saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

The issue is that it is saving the file as .xls which is a legacy extension for old Excel file formats but if I chang eit to .xlsx I get an error that the file extension or file format is not valid. Can someone please let me know what change do I need to make to make it work for .xlsx extension.

Thanks

Comment: Try: `{type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8'}`.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't open as xlsx..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498713/how-to-export-an-html-table-as-an-xlsx-file seems like it is not possible by javascript