# HTML table copy paste data to Excel without 1000s separator

Tags: c#, html, excel, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Server code generates HTML table (Bootstrap 3), where numbers for easy reading are formatted with 1000s / group separator as space. This is done with `.ToString("#,0.00")`. However space is encoded in HTML as `&nbsp;`. This creates a problem once copied and pasted into Excel, as is not recognised as a number.

I am looking for a solution how to solve this, so that the numbers in html table pasted into Excel will be recognised as numbers, without need for cleaning it up in Excel.

Update 1.

This legacy ASP.NET WebForms application. I have tried both `<%# %>` (data-binding expression) and `<%#: %>` (HTML encoded data-binding expression) server-side scripting delimiters. However both to my surprise encode space as `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Are ordinary spaces pasted into Excel correctly? You can create a custom culture with thousand separator set to ordinary space instead of non-breaking one and use it when converting numbers to string then.

Comment: Yes, Excel manages ordinary space. However problem is with data-binding expression, which converts ordinary space coming from `.ToString` into `&nbsp;`. So user will always copy number with `&nbsp;` instead of ordinary space.

Comment: There is a firefox addon "TableToExcel" you can use this. Or why don't you add a download button next to your table. Download as XLSX.

Comment: @Charles That would be my last resort solution, as html table is pretty complex, and does not constitute simple monolithic table, some rows are of different format where values are calculated in server code. But for most rows data come from database.

Comment: `.ToString()` uses the current culture if not specified otherwise. You can provide the custom culture as a second argument, or override the current culture globally. In your custom culture you can set `NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` (or `CurrencyGroupSeparator`, depending on format string) to an ordinary space.

Comment: This is a JavaScript lib that looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44211817/11808788

Comment: @AlexSkalozub I have found out that default `NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` was a non-breaking space, what caused the issue. Eventually I have created my own culture with real space as 1000s separator, which I pass into `ToString` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are ordinary spaces pasted into Excel correctly? You can create a custom culture with thousand separator set to ordinary space instead of non-breaking one and use it when converting numbers to string then